# add and remove css class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

So I have this code and it works:

```
$('.col-main').on('mouseenter', '.product-wrapper', function () {
  $( this ).addClass( "js-hover" );
});
$('.col-main').on('mouseleave', '.product-wrapper', function () {
  $( this ).removeClass( "js-hover" );
});
```

But I want it to be a bit more elegant. Something like this:

```
listContainer.on( {
  mouseenter: function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "js-hover" );
    console.log( "hoooover" );
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "js-hover" );
  }
}, productWrapper );
```

But I can´t get it to work :) Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use CSS `:hover` pseudo-selector.

Comment: As said @Tushar use `.product-wrapper:hover{/*your css of js-hover class*/}`

Comment: The question is about how get the js code working... Pretend I want to add a new element.. ;)

Comment: @Tushar, @Yoplaboom, had the same thought at first, but you can't change the style of a node with css, if hover occurs on some child-selector. sth like `.col-main .product-wrapper:hover { /* change .col-mains style */ }`

Comment: @Thomas Yes, we can. `parent:hover child {...}`

Comment: **that is not, what the js code does.** your example changes the style of child, if parent is hovered, the js-code changes the style of parent, if this specific child is hovered, __not if parent is hovered, and not if some other child-node is hovered.__ and this can't be done in css (yet)

Comment: Why I'm targeting the parent is because child elements are added dynamically.. when added that way they lose the binding if I target the child directly...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery hover and toggle functions could be useful to you.

```
$('.element-selector').hover(function(){   
  $(this).toggleClass('.class-to-toggle');
}, function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('.class-to-toggle');
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdso2219/

Update

---

Since you have now mentioned that this needs to work for dynamic elements, modify the .hover to .live, eg:

```
$('.element-selector').live('mouseenter', function(){   
  $(this).toggleClass('.class-to-toggle');
}).live('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('.class-to-toggle');
})
```

Comment: I think that .hover wont work on dynamic added elements?

Comment: @Mackelito Sorry, you didn't mention dynamically added elements.

Comment: yeah.. sorry about that.. but .live is deprecated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `productWrapper` variable. Try like followoing.

```
var listContainer=$('.col-main')
var productWrapper='.product-wrapper';

listContainer.on( {
    mouseenter: function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "js-hover" );
        console.log( "hoooover" );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "js-hover" );
   }
}, productWrapper );
```

Answer (score 0):

sth like this?

```
$('.col-main').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.product-wrapper', function (e) {
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'js-hover', e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```